# Defining APIs in microservices using DDD fashion

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design

My sample DDD system contains two microservices, each of them defined for specific context - User domain microservice and Estate domain microservice.

I am well aware that aggreagte roots are single entry points for management of bussiness entities, f.e. User (an aggregate) can be owner of an Estate (an aggregate from second context), so the management of estates is executed through UserAggregate.

What I cannot fully understand is how does it apply in terms of design of APIs and use cases - assume that I have created my profile, and I want to add an Estate as my belonging.

How can I determine if I should send request to

/user_domain/{user_id}/addNewEstate - retrieve the User from the database, try to add an Estate which enforces business rules defined (f.e. maximum of 5 estates), and then replicate the change in EstateService (create the entity and save it within Estate context)

or to

/estate_domain/addnewEstate?userId=sampleId - which would simply call the UserContext to check if the user exists, and If he does, create the estate (applying business rules) and persist it.

Answer (score 1):

If we talk DDD, then User cannot be an estate owner. It is another bounded context.

You can introduce Owner aggregate in Estate context.
I don't know what is the business task of Estate, but most there could be both the case when an estate belongs to an owner (think AirB'n'B), or when it is an independent aggregate root (think cadaster domain).

Owner then can be associated with User from another context by id. Most likely owner is created after a user has signed up. User is a login. But owner means passing some checks, signing agreements and passing other business rules.

Then the endpoint would look like POST /estate_domain/owner/1234/property/